# How can I detect a successful login on a separate application?

Tags: python, python-3.x, authentication, automation

I am making a automation script on python to read a dump of accounts from a .txt file and trying each of them onto the application. The script works so far but after a log in is successful the program keeps running. The application is the Minecraft Launcher if anyone finds it helpful.

```
import pyautogui
import time

aclist = open("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\dropmc.txt", "r")
content = aclist.read().splitlines()
for i in content:
    i = i.split(':')
    # The code to type in username and password was here, its just mouse movement and clicks
    # After the final mouse click, I want to be able to check if the login was successful
aclist.close()
```

Comment: Are there any errors that happen after a login is successful and the script keeps trying? If so, you could use try and except to catch the "error" and stop the script.

Comment: No, there are no errors if a login is successful